# What is used for border parameter?

Tags: opengl

I'm learning OpenGL and have a question. I read about Texturing and found border param in glCopyTexImage and glCompressedTexImage functions. In book: "OpenGL Programming Guide" wrote that border is reserved and must be zero? If it reserved why they place it into parameter?

P.S.: I have one idea, is it used for border texture? Like don't read data below that border, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *modern* OpenGL border is required to be 0, but in *legacy* OpenGL it could have had a value of either 0 or 1.  A good source of documentation for this, and similar legacy OpenGL quirks, is the MSDN site: [glTexImage](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexImage2D).

The purpose of a non-0 border is for the GL_CLAMP texture wrap mode (set via [glTexParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368641(v=vs.85).aspx)); quoting from the MSDN documentation:

> Border texture elements are accessed only if wrapping is set to GL_CLAMP

This wrap mode is also deprecated in OpenGL, and the old concept of border texels no longer exists (modern OpenGL instead has GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER and border colors).

The *border* parameter was, however, retained in glTexImage (and friends) to avoid having to change the API.  When the API did eventually change (to [glTexStorage](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexStorage2D)) you'll note that there is no longer a *border* parameter.